# how can uniquely sign in an android application with a facebook account

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android application. If a user want to use the application he must sign in with a facebook account. 
My problem is when a user remains sign in from an android terminal and then he sign in from another android terminal through the same facebook account.

Is there any way to uniquely identify a user from a facebook application ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "another android terminal"? and why is multiple login a problem?

Comment: another android terminal is any other device that supports android and multiple log in is a problem because i want to offer my user some services by his location

Comment: How is the location transferred to the second device?

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, how does the location from device 'A' show on device 'B'?

Comment: i don't know at this moment, i investigate this problem too

Comment: Unless you're sharing the data across the Facebook application, it won't happen that way. Each login is a unique session with the data provided by the device. If you're doing things right It won't matter if the user logs in from two different locations even at the same time.